# JRebel doesn't update HTML

Tags: java, html, intellij-idea, wicket, jrebel

I'm using JRebel 5.0.0 in Intellij IDEA (Leda preview, 122.746) with JRebel plug-in. The server is GlassFish v3.1.
My application uses Wicket, with HTML templates placed in the same place as classes.

The problem is that updated classes do successfully reload after project rebuild, but updated HTMLs do not. For instance, I can add an element both to the page class and to the HTML, and then get an exception from Wicket saying that this element is referenced in the code, but absent in the markup.

Updated HTML resources and recompiled classes end up in the same directory (which I've checked), this directory is present in `rebel.xml` (and this setup is valid because recompiled classes are indeed updated).

What might be the problem?

Comment: And yes, wicket_plugin is enabled in the plugin settings.

Comment: Please ask this question from JRebel forums - the support staff will need to see jrebel.log to help you with this.

Comment: What does your rebel.xml look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that was completely my fault, and kind of a stupid one.

I just haven't noticed a `<wicket:extend>` tag in the edited HTML, so my updates ended up ignored.

HTML refresh does actually work, everything runs smoothly even without clearing markup cache (thanks to a Wicket plug-in).

Comment: The only cases where reload does not work is when you remove a markup file, as the make in your IDE does not delete the html files in the target folder, wicket still sees it and use it. That's not big deal though.